# Using Photoshop, how can I remove words from a sign?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I am trying to remove words from a sign on a picture I took.

As an example, I found this picture below.  Given the following image, how could I remove the letters on the sign (where it says "MARINA" or "HOBURGS BANK" for example) and replace it with the background that is behind it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success with the **Spot Healing Brush** tool.

[image]

You just have to select a brush size that matches the height of a letter, and then click and drag over a bunch of letters. Photoshop will try to remove the black letters and replace them with the surrounding background.

Not particularly a 100% perfect solution, but that was done in 10 seconds.

[image]

Comment: 2 quick for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I would use the clone tool on that. It would reproduce the colors and the noise that exists , making the change seamless.

Comment: … but you did a bit more :P — generally, I don't like the clone tool as much as the healing tool, because it leaves harder edges and doesn't automatically create smooth transitions.